# Problems using .NET Upgrade Assistant plugin migrating from .NET 4.7 to .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have to migrate my project from .NET 4.7 to .NET 8.0. The easiest way seems use this tool, so I installed it and I see it in Visual Studio 2022.

But when I right-click on my `.csproj` file, I don't see any update option.

I reloaded Visual Studio and the extension is enabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Upgrade", under the "Publish..."

Comment: You don't right click the `.csproj` file, You should right click the project in the VS Solutions Explorer. as shown in the [MS Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website)

Comment: Any update? Did you encounter new errors?